# What are the benefits of using BaseSubscriber hooks vs Subscriber methods in spring Reactor?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

[projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#_an_alternative_to_lambdas_basesubscriber) documentation shows an implementation of `BaseSubscriber` as an alternative to using lambdas in a subscription, however by reading the reference docs: [BaseSubscriber](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/BaseSubscriber.html) I fail to see how overriding any of the hooks achieves anything that overriding `Subscriber` base methods would not. Why should we use `BaseSubscriber` at all?

Comment: What do you mean by subscriber base methods?

Comment: the methods in the Subscriber interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseSubscriber` implements book-keeping and guards in the `Subscriber` methods so you don't have to write that boilerplate and worry the boilerplate is correct / covering all bases (eg. protection against exceptions in `onNext`/`onSubscribe`/etc... and translation of said exceptions into `onError` signals).

Note that when you use the lambda-based versions of `Flux#subscribe`, it creates a pretty similar `LambdaSubscriber` with the same kind of boilerplate.

Then in both case you as the developer are only left with implementing the business logic. In one case, it's through provided lambdas, and in the case of `BaseSubscriber` it's through implementing the `hookXxx` methods.

The main difference between the lambda approach and the `BaseSubscriber` one is in lambdas you cannot access state other than the lambda's input parameter. With `BaseSubscriber`, we specifically capture the `Subscription` and the hooks methods can `cancel()` or `request(n)` that subscription.